# How to use DATETIME_SUB function in where clause Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get data for 7 days from Bigquery table. The table has a column with datetime of hits.
I used this query, but i got "This query returned no results."

```
select * 
from  `table` t
where hitTime between TIMESTAMP(DATETIME_SUB("2018-02-07 00:00:00", INTERVAL 7 DAY)) and TIMESTAMP("2018-02-07 00:00:00")
```

What mistake did i make?

p/s/ there isn't the tabble_suffix

Answer (score 0):

If `hitTime` is a `timestamp`, use `timestamp_sub`:

```
where hitTime between TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) and
                      TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work - your syntax is correct. Given the result was `This query returned no results.` and not an error, it's likely you don't have any rows in that date range in your table. Have you checked this?